# File manager plays mp3s via blutooth, but neither firefox nor chromium will stream via blutooth, please help, thanks!

Tags: sound, firefox, chromium

I can listen to mp3s via blutooth from the file system, in other words on my hard drive, but when I try to stream sound from either Firefox or Chromium the sound comes out my computer speakers.  I will continue to search, but honestly am stumped.  Thank you for any help or ideas.

Comment: Sorry, new to asking, Linux Mint 21.0 Vanessa, AMD 64.

Comment: Hi, Mint is different than Ubuntu. If you use the snap, then please file a bug to Firefox or Chromium, e.g. `ubuntu-bug chromium` (preferred) or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+filebug, with as much detail as you can provide.